# An ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{210}[X]$ that is not maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

I need to find an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{210}[X]$ that is not maximal and I need to find a maximal ideal that contains it.

Here is my reasoning: let $\pi:\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}_{210}[X]$ be the reduction modulo $210$ (i.e. the homomorphism that reduces all the coefficients of a polynomial modulo $210$). Then by the correspondence theorem for ideals I know that I have a bijection between the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{210}[X]$ and the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ that contain the ideal $210\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Hence, my problem reduces to finding an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ that contains $210\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and is not maximal. Such an example is $105\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and the corresponding ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{210}[X]$ is $\hat{105}\mathbb{Z}_{210}[X]$.

For the second part of the problem, we have $105\mathbb{Z}[X]\subset (5, X^2+X+1)$ and this is a maximal ideal because $5$ is a prime and $X^2+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. The corresponding maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{210}[X]$ is $(\hat{5}, X^2+X+\hat{1})$ and now we are done.

I would like to know if this whole reasoning is correct. I know that for such a question it is enough to provide the two ideals that the questions asks for, but I want to make sure that my reasoning was sound and I wasn't just lucky.

Comment: Of course, $\{0\}$ is a perfectly good non-maximal ideal, which would make the question easier.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes, I agree, I tried to find a non-zero non-maximal ideal in order to make it more interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is correct, as far as I can tell!

About the second part, you are right that the ideal $(5, X^2+X+1)\subseteq\Bbb Z[X]$ is maximal, but the reasoning is not correct. For instance let's run the same argument for $(5, X^2+1)$. $5$ is prime and $X^2+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z[X]$, but the ideal $(5, X^2+1)$ is not maximal (not even prime!). There are two ways to see this:

- The quotient $$\Bbb Z[X]/(5, X^2+1)\cong\Bbb Z_5[i]$$ But $5=(1+2i)(1-2i)$, so the ring has zero-divisors thus the ideal is not maximal. That is, $X^2+1$ has roots in $\Bbb Z_5$.
- We can write the ideal $(5,X^2+1)=(5,X^2-4)$ and we notice that $X^2-4\in (5, X^2-4)$, but $X-2,X+2\not\in (5, X^2-4)$, so the ideal is not prime.

What makes $(5, X^2+X+1)$ work is that $X^2+X+1$ is also irreducible in $\Bbb Z_5$, that is, the quotient $$\Bbb Z[X]/(5,X^2+X+1)\cong \Bbb Z_5[X]/(X^2+X+1)\cong\Bbb F_{25}$$ is a field.

Comment: Oh, right, thank you! It was a typo, I forgot to add the underscore $5$. Thank you for pointing that out and taking your time to read my reasoning!

Comment: @TheZone You’re welcome!